# How to select rows from a 3-D Tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor `logits` with the dimensions `[batch_size, num_rows, num_coordinates]` (i.e. each logit in the batch is a matrix). In my case batch size is 2, there's 4 rows and 4 coordinates.

```
logits = tf.constant([[[10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0],
                      [11.0, 10.0, 10.0, 30.0],
                      [12.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0],
                      [13.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0]],
                     [[14.0, 11.0, 21.0, 31.0],
                      [15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0],
                      [16.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0],
                      [17.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0]]])
```

I want to select the first and second row of the first batch and the second and fourth row of the second batch.

```
indices = tf.constant([[0, 1], [1, 3]])
```

So the desired output would be

```
logits = tf.constant([[[10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0],
                      [11.0, 10.0, 10.0, 30.0]],
                     [[15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0],
                      [17.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0]]])
```

How do I do this using TensorFlow? I tried using `tf.gather(logits, indices)` but it did not return what I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible in TensorFlow, but slightly inconvenient, because [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/tf/gather) currently only works with one-dimensional indices, and only selects slices from the 0th dimension of a tensor. However, it is still possible to solve your problem efficiently, by transforming the arguments so that they can be passed to `tf.gather()`:

```
logits = ... # [2 x 4 x 4] tensor
indices = tf.constant([[0, 1], [1, 3]])

# Use tf.shape() to make this work with dynamic shapes.
batch_size = tf.shape(logits)[0]
rows_per_batch = tf.shape(logits)[1]
indices_per_batch = tf.shape(indices)[1]

# Offset to add to each row in indices. We use `tf.expand_dims()` to make 
# this broadcast appropriately.
offset = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size) * rows_per_batch, 1)

# Convert indices and logits into appropriate form for `tf.gather()`. 
flattened_indices = tf.reshape(indices + offset, [-1])
flattened_logits = tf.reshape(logits, tf.concat(0, [[-1], tf.shape(logits)[2:]]))

selected_rows = tf.gather(flattened_logits, flattened_indices)

result = tf.reshape(selected_rows,
                    tf.concat(0, [tf.pack([batch_size, indices_per_batch]),
                                  tf.shape(logits)[2:]]))
```

Note that, since this uses [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) and not [`tf.transpose()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/tf/transpose), it doesn't need to modify the (potentially large) data in the `logits` tensor, so it should be fairly efficient.

Comment: While your answer is great, I think today it can be replaced with `tf.gather_nd`, which was probably not yet available at the time of your writing (see my answer)

Answer (score 4):

mrry's answer is great, but I think with the function [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) the problem can be solved with much fewer lines of code (probably this function was not yet available at the time of mrry's writing):

```
logits = tf.constant([[[10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0],
                      [11.0, 10.0, 10.0, 30.0],
                      [12.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0],
                      [13.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0]],
                     [[14.0, 11.0, 21.0, 31.0],
                      [15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0],
                      [16.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0],
                      [17.0, 11.0, 11.0, 21.0]]])

indices = tf.constant([[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 3]]])

result = tf.gather_nd(logits, indices)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
```

This will print

```
[[[ 10.  10.  20.  20.]
  [ 11.  10.  10.  30.]]

 [[ 15.  11.  11.  21.]
  [ 17.  11.  11.  21.]]]
```

[`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) should be available as of v0.10. Check out [this github issue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) for more discussions on this.

Comment: how did you change indices to 3d from 2d (as asked in question) ?

Comment: @Tulsi I don't understand your question. There is no mention of 3D indices in the question, or is there?