# How to slice tensor with dynamc shape in tensorflow?

Tags: slice, tensorflow

Say there is a tensor `state` containing a list of rnn states, and another tensor `prob` containing the probabilities of each state.

```py
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 49, 32])
print state.get_shape()  # (?, 49, 32) (batch_size, candidate_size, state_size)

prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 49])
print prob.get_shape() # (?, 49) (batch_size, candidate_size)

# Now I want to fetch 7 states with top probabilities
_, indices = tf.nn.top_k(prob, 7)
print indices.get_shape() # (?, 7)
```

How can I slice `state` with `indices`?

---

#### EDIT:

The issue with using `tf.gather(state, indices)` is that it will only slice `state` along the **first dimension**, which is the batch dimension. Here we want to slice it along the second dimension (of length 49).

Comment: See this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764791/in-tensorflow-how-to-use-tf-gather-for-the-last-dimension/36777781#36777781

Comment: This seems work, the shape is right. Thanks a lot!