# Tensorflow tf.gather with axis parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow's `tf.gather` to get elements from a multidimensional array like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = tf.constant([0, 1, 1])
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])

result = tf.gather(x, indices, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    selection = sess.run(result)
    print(selection)
```

which results in:

```
[[1 2 2]
 [4 5 5]
 [7 8 8]]
```

what I want though is:

```
[1
 5
 8]
```

how can I use `tf.gather` to apply the single indices on the specified axis?
(Same result as the workaround specified in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845855/9763766)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `indices` to `full indices`, and using `gather_nd`. Can be achieved by doing:

```
result = tf.squeeze(tf.gather_nd(x,tf.stack([tf.range(indices.shape[0])[...,tf.newaxis], indices[...,tf.newaxis]], axis=2)))
```