# Select weight of action from a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have a small model used in a reinforcement learning context.

I can input a 2d tensor of states, and I get a 2d tensor of action weigths.

Let say I input two states and I get the following action weights out:

```
[[0.1, 0.2],
 [0.3, 0.4]]
```

Now I have another 2d tensor which have the action number from which I want to get the weights:

```
[[1],
 [0]]
```

How can I use this tensor to get the weight of actions?

In this example I'd like to get:

```
[[0.2],
 [0.3]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464010/tensorflow-tf-gather-with-axis-parameter/50464997#50464997

Comment: I think it's not the same because his indices array and the output are 1d. The answer might be a bit different in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [Tensorflow tf.gather with axis parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464010/tensorflow-tf-gather-with-axis-parameter/50464997#50464997), the indices are handled little different here:

```
a = tf.constant( [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]])
indices = tf.constant([[1],[0]])

# convert to full indices
full_indices = tf.stack([tf.range(indices.shape[0])[...,tf.newaxis], indices], axis=2)

# gather
result = tf.gather_nd(a,full_indices)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(result))
#[[0.2]
#[0.3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is squeeze the dimensions of indices, element-wise multiply with corresponding one-hot vector and then expand the dimensions later.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

weights = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]])
indices = tf.constant([[1], [0]])
# Reduce from 2d (2, 1) to 1d (2,)
indices1d = tf.squeeze(indices)
# One-hot vector corresponding to the indices. shape (2, 2)
action_one_hot = tf.one_hot(indices=indices1d, depth=weights.shape[1])
# Element-wise multiplication and sum across axis 1 to pick the weight. Shape (2,)
action_taken_weight = tf.reduce_sum(action_one_hot * weights, axis=1)
# Expand the dimension back to have a 2d. Shape (2, 1)
action_taken_weight2d = tf.expand_dims(action_taken_weight, axis=1)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print("weights\n", sess.run(weights))
print("indices\n", sess.run(indices))
print("indices1d\n", sess.run(indices1d))
print("action_one_hot\n", sess.run(action_one_hot))
print("action_taken_weight\n", sess.run(action_taken_weight))
print("action_taken_weight2d\n", sess.run(action_taken_weight2d))
```

Should give you the following output:

```py
weights
 [[0.1 0.2]
 [0.3 0.4]]
indices
 [[1]
 [0]]
indices1d
 [1 0]
action_one_hot
 [[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
action_taken_weight
 [0.2 0.3]
action_taken_weight2d
 [[0.2]
 [0.3]]
```

> Note: You can also do action_taken_weight = `tf.reshape(action_taken_weight, tf.shape(indices))` instead of expand_dims.