# tensorflow gather across multiple dimentions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

`gather(params, indices)` does the following

```
output[i, ..., j, :, ... :] = params[indices[i, ..., j], :, ..., :]
```

so if you have 4-dimensional params and 2-dimensional indices, you end up having 5-dimensional array as a result

the question is how to do

```
output[i, ..., j, :, ... :] = params[indices[i, :], ..., indices[j, :], :, ..., :]
```

so that it acts as `numpy's`

`output = params[indices[0], indices[1], .. , :]`

(the #206 ticket on github is regarding different issue: it is about numpy-like api, not gathering in general)

one possible way is to use `gather_nd`, but (as far as I understand) if we want to `gather_nd` over not all dimensions, we still have to create indices for them, e.g. if we have 10-dimensional array A and we want to index first two dimensions with 2-dimensional array B, like A[B[0], B[1], :] our indices matrix would have to have 11 columns (with 8 redundant).

```
--- old indices ----       new index
0 0 <all rows of length 8> 0
1 1 <all rows of length 8> 1
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an update on [#206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206) that @ebrevdo is working on generalizing slicing.

Meanwhile, you could flatten your array, construct linear indices for the elements you want, use gather, then reshape back, like was done in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088277/how-to-select-rows-from-a-3-d-tensor-in-tensorflow/36088778#36088778) by mrry. That's probably not much worse in efficiency than a native implementation