# Retrieving last value of LSTM sequence in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I have sequences of different lengths that I want to classify using LSTMs in Tensorflow. For the classification I just need the LSTM output of the last timestep of each sequence.

```
max_length = 10
n_dims = 2
layer_units = 5
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, n_dims])
lengths =  tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=layer_units, state_is_tuple=True)

sequence_outputs, last_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, sequence_length=lengths, inputs=input)
```

I would like to get, in NumPy notation: `output = sequence_outputs[:,lengths]`

Is there any way or workaround to get this behaviour in Tensorflow?

---UPDATE---

Following this post [How to select rows from a 3-D Tensor in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088277/how-to-select-rows-from-a-3-d-tensor-in-tensorflow) it seems that is possible to solve the problem in an efficient manner with `tf.gather` and manipulating the indices. The only requirement is that the batch size must be known in advance. Here is the adaptation of the referred post to this concrete problem:

```
max_length = 10
n_dims = 2
layer_units = 5
batch_size = 2
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, max_length, n_dims])
lengths =  tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=layer_units, state_is_tuple=True)

sequence_outputs, last_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,
                                                  sequence_length=lengths, inputs=input)

#Code adapted from @mrry response in StackOverflow:
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088277/how-to-select-rows-from-a-3-d-tensor-in-tensorflow
rows_per_batch = tf.shape(input)[1]
indices_per_batch = 1

# Offset to add to each row in indices. We use `tf.expand_dims()` to make 
# this broadcast appropriately.
offset = tf.range(0, batch_size) * rows_per_batch

# Convert indices and logits into appropriate form for `tf.gather()`. 
flattened_indices = lengths - 1 + offset
flattened_sequence_outputs = tf.reshape(self.sequence_outputs, tf.concat(0, [[-1],
                             tf.shape(sequence_outputs)[2:]]))

selected_rows = tf.gather(flattened_sequence_outputs, flattened_indices)
last_output  = tf.reshape(selected_rows,
                          tf.concat(0, [tf.pack([batch_size, indices_per_batch]),
                          tf.shape(self.sequence_outputs)[2:]]))
```

@petrux option ([Get the last output of a dynamic_rnn in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273361/get-th-last-output-of-a-dynamic-rnn-in-tensorflow/41273737#41273737)) seems also to work but the need of building a list within a for loop may be less optimized, although I did not perform any benchmark to support this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273737/1861627) could be an answer. I don't think there is anything similar to the NumPy notation you pointed out, but the effect is the same.

Comment: It seems to work. it seems that the advance indexing I was looking for is an open issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638

I just wonder if your implementation will decrease efficiency much or it will be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, using [gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), where batch size does not need to be known ahead of time.

```
def extract_axis_1(data, ind):
    """
    Get specified elements along the first axis of tensor.
    :param data: Tensorflow tensor that will be subsetted.
    :param ind: Indices to take (one for each element along axis 0 of data).
    :return: Subsetted tensor.
    """

    batch_range = tf.range(tf.shape(data)[0])
    indices = tf.stack([batch_range, ind], axis=1)
    res = tf.gather_nd(data, indices)

    return res

output = extract_axis_1(sequence_outputs, lengths - 1)
```

Now `output` is a tensor of dimension `[batch_size, num_cells]`.