# How to enlarge a matrix in tensorflow without duplicating values?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

What I am trying to do is have a weight matrix for my neural network which grows in size (i.e. a neuron is added to it each iteration). However, I do not want to use `tf.Variable` again as this will waste memory by copying the values in the previous matrix not expanding the matrix itself.

I have seen that people use tf.assign with validate_shape set to False, however, this does not change the shape of the variable correctly which I believed was a bug but the tensorflow GitHub did not seem to agree (I don't understand why from their [reply](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10091#issuecomment-304489870)).

Below is a simplified example of the problem. x is the matrix that I want to expand so that it can be added to z. If anyone knows a solution to what I am trying to achieve here I would be very grateful =)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Initialise some variables
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 4], stddev = 0.04))
z = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 4], stddev = 0.04))
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([x, z]))

# Enlarge the matrix by assigning it a new set of values
sess.run(tf.assign(x, tf.concat((x, tf.cast(tf.truncated_normal([1, 4], stddev = 0.04), tf.float32)), 0), validate_shape=False))

# Print shapes of matrices, notice that x's actual shape is different for the
# shape tensorflow has recorded for it
print(x.get_shape())
print(x.eval(session=sess).shape)
print(z.get_shape())
print(z.eval(session=sess).shape)

# Add two matrices with equal shapes
print(tf.add(x, z).eval(session=sess))
```

Note: I realize that if I initialized z to the shape (2, 4) and then expanded it with tf.assign (as I do with x) the above example will work. But due to another constraint, I cannot control the original shape of z.

Answer (score 0):

Tensors in tensorflow are immutable, so you can't re-scale them easily.

You can attempt to pad with 0's and then access parts of the matrix with tf.gather() as shown here [How to select rows from a 3-D Tensor in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088277/how-to-select-rows-from-a-3-d-tensor-in-tensorflow)

to effect the "submatrix" within the larger padded matrix. This however does not seem to be an easy or elegant solution.