# Convert 2d tensor to 3d in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I need to convert 2d tensor to a 3d tensor. how can I transfer this in tensor flow.

---

```
[[30, 29, 19, 17, 12, 11],
       [30, 27, 20, 16,  5,  1],
       [28, 25, 17, 14,  7,  2],
       [28, 26, 21, 14,  6,  4]]
```

to this

```
[[[0,30], [0,29], [0,19], [0,17], [0,12], [0,11]],
       [[1,30], [1,27], [1,20], [1,16],[1,5], [1,1]],
       [[2,28], [2,25], [2,17], [2,14], [2,7],  [2,2]],
       [[3,28], [3,26], [3,21], [3,14], [3,6],  [3,4]]]
```

Thanks! I am doing this to implement asked in [How to select rows from a 3-D Tensor in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088277/how-to-select-rows-from-a-3-d-tensor-in-tensorflow) @kom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround to achieve the `3D` tensor from `2D` tensor

```
a = tf.constant([[30, 29, 19, 17, 12, 11],
   [30, 27, 20, 16,  5,  1],
   [28, 25, 17, 14,  7,  2],
   [28, 26, 21, 14,  6,  4]], dtype=tf.int32)
a = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=2)

b = tf.constant(np.asarray([i*np.ones(a.shape[1]) for i in range(0, a.shape[0])], dtype=np.int32), dtype=tf.int32)
b = tf.expand_dims(b, axis=2)

final_ids = tf.concat([b, a], axis=2)
```

Comment: In your second statement exapnd_dims() should be expand_dims().

Comment: if shape of a variable like (5 (batch_size), ? ) then a.shape[1] throws an error.

Comment: Just to answer @Tulsi comment, one could use -1 as shape when you don't know the shape. In the example of (5,?) u could say (5,-1)